# Find two arithmetic progressions of three square numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I want to know if it is possible to find two arithmetic progressions of three square numbers, with the same common difference:

\begin{align}
\ & a^2 +r = b^2 \\
  & b^2 +r = c^2  \\ 
& a^2 +c^2 = 2\,b^2  \\ 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\ & d^2 +r = e^2 \\
  & e^2 +r = f^2  \\ 
& d^2 +f^2 = 2e^2  \\ 
\end{align}

where $a,b,c,d,r \in \Bbb N$.

Here is an example that almost works:

\begin{align}
\ & 23^2 +41496 = 205^2 \\
  & 205^2 + 41496 = 289^2  \\ 
& 23^2 +289^2 = 2\,(205)^2  \\ 
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\ & 373^2 + 41496 = 425^2 \\
  & 425^2 + 41496 = \color{#C00000}{222121}  \\ 
& 23^2 + \color{#C00000}{222121} = 2\,(205)^2  \\ 
\end{align}

where the difference is $41496$, but the last element isn't a square number.

I can't find an example of two progressions with three numbers and the same common difference. Could you demonstrate that such progressions are nonexistent using reductio ad absurdum to this statement?

Comment: The correct formulation of the problem - is half of its solution.  2 and 3 equations are equivalent to each other. It is necessary to solve a system of 2 equations. As elementary as it is solved with a different view of the difference of squares.

Comment: $$r=b^2-a^2=c^2-b^2$$ It is necessary to solve this equation. More than anything do not have to deal.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1051335_pythagorean_triple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many solutions to the system,

\begin{align}
\ & a^2 +r_1 = b^2 \\
  & b^2 +r_1 = c^2  \\ 
& a^2 +c^2 = 2b^2  \\ 
\hline
\ & d^2 +r_2 = e^2 \\
  & e^2 +r_2 = f^2  \\ 
& d^2 +f^2 = 2e^2  \\ 
\end{align}

with $\color{blue}{r_1=r_2}$. Eliminating $r_1$ between the first two equations (and similarly for $r_2$), one must solve the Pythagorean-like,

$$a^2+c^2=2b^2\\ d^2+f^2=2e^2$$

which has solution,

$$a,b,c = p^2 - 2q^2,\; p^2 + 2p q + 2q^2,\; p^2 + 4p q + 2q^2\\ d,e,f = r^2 - 2s^2,\; r^2 + 2r s + 2s^2,\; r^2 + 4r s + 2s^2$$

Hence,

$$r_1 = -a^2+b^2 = -b^2+c^2 = 4 p q (p + q) (p + 2 q)\\ r_2 = -d^2+e^2 = -e^2+f^2 = 4 r s (r + s) (r + 2 s)$$

Thus one must solve,

$$p q (p + q) (p + 2 q) =  r s (r + s) (r + 2 s)$$

This is essentially the same equation in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3246815/4781), hence one solution (among many) is,

$$p,\;q = 2 n (m + 6 n),\; m (m + 4 n)\\
\;r,\;s = m (m + 2 n),\; 4 n (m + 3 n)$$

For example, let $m,n = 1,1$, then,

$$a,b,c = 146, 386, 526\\  d,e,f = 503, 617, 713\\ r_1=r_2= 127680$$

and so on.

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is far better than the accepted answer. Well done! $(+1)$

Comment: @MrPie: Thank you, MrPie. I was late to the party, unfortunately.

Comment: I think you deserve a tick/checkmark, but unfortunately, there can only be one... *fortunately* however, giving your answer some time for further review, I might give you a bounty to make up for the tick. Many answers are in the same boat as you, but you are nearing 30k rep, so... special occasion ;)

Comment: @MrPie: That's ok, I enjoy these type of questions. But that's a nice thought. :)

Answer (score 4):

$$(a,b,c,d,e,f,r)=(1,29,41,23,37,47,840)$$
satisfies 
$$a^2 +r = b^2,\quad b^2 +r = c^2,\quad a^2 +c^2 = 2b^2$$
$$d^2 +r = e^2,\quad e^2 +r = f^2,\quad d^2 +f^2 = 2e^2$$