# Solution to a Third degree diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have two diophantine equations of the third degree viz.$$2b_1^3l_1+3b_1^2l_1^2+b_1l_1^3=k$$ and $$2b_2^3l_2+3b_2^2l_2^2+b_2l_2^3=k$$ The aim is to find distinct values of $(l_i,b_i)$ which satisfy this solution. For example both $(3,2)$ and $(5,1)$ give $k=210$. I would like to know if exists a recursive method to find all values of $k$ where multiple solutions are possible, if all the variables are constrained to be positive. Like some Chinese remainder theorem or something? If yes, is there a way to compute them?

Comment: You seem to have written the same equation twice.  Did you intend any differences?

Comment: It is not the same.. The coefficients are $l_1,b_1$ in the first and $l_2,b_2$ in the second.. I wish to find unique values of the $(l_i,b_i)$ pair to satisfy this.

Comment: Do you have any structural reason to believe such a method to find suitable $k$s exists?  Even the question of which integers can be represented as sums of three cubes is unresolved for the equivalent of $k = 42$...  [42 is the new 33 - Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASoz_NuIvP0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP wishes to find more examples of,

$$2b_1^3l_1+3b_1^2l_1^2+b_1l_1^3=2b_2^3l_2+3b_2^2l_2^2+b_2l_2^3=k\tag1$$

or equivalently,

$$p q (p + q) (2 p + q) = r s (r + s) (2 r + s)=k\tag2$$

One solution to this is,

$$p,q = 3,4\\ r,s = 5,2$$

with $k=840$ and which obviously has the auxiliary relation $p+q = r+s$. So let,

$$p,\;q = a + b + c,\; -a - b + c\\
\;r,\;s = -a + b + c,\; a - b + c\;$$

to satisfy this relation, and $(2)$ simplifies as,

$$a^2+3b^2+6bc-c^2 = 0\tag3$$

with solution

$$c = 3b\pm\sqrt{a^2+12b^2}$$

and easily solved in the integers. Hence,

$$p,\;q = m (m + 4 n),\; 2 n (m + 6 n)\\
\;r,\;s = 4 n (m + 3 n),\;  m (m + 2 n)$$

for **any** $m,n$. For example, let $m,n = 1,1$, then,

$$p,\;q = 5,\;14\\
\;r,\;s = 16,\;3$$

which yields $k = 31920$. And so on.

Comment: The OP's example, $$p,\;q = 3,\;2\\ r,\;s = 5,\;1$$ has auxiliary relation $p+q = r$. This family also has infinitely many integer solutions but needs an elliptic curve.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how do we deal with using elliptic curve.  How can I convert it to an elliptic? Also do these two classes i.e. $p+q=r+s$ and $p+q=r$ cover all such equations?

Comment: I still have a few questions regarding this. I shall ask when you are on, if it is okay for you.

Answer (score 3):

You have the equation $2 x^3 y + 3 x^2 y^2 + x y^3 = k$ and are wanting to find the number of solutions (and their values) for particular values of $k$.

It is worthwhile to note here that the change of variables $\{x \mapsto -x, y \mapsto -y \}$ leaves this equation unchanged, so every solution has a sign reversed pair.  For instance, your $(k,x,y) = (210, 2, 3)$ solution immediately gives the solution $(210,-2,-3)$.  We will not continue to discuss these sign-reversed pairs by assuming $x \geq 0$ and should $x = 0$ in a solution, we talk about the $y > 0$ member of its pair.

The polynomial in the equation factors as
$$  (x)(y)(x+y)(2x+y) = k  \text{,}  $$
so $x$ divides $k$, $y$ divides $k$, $x+y$ divides $k$, and $2x+y$ divides $k$.

This factorization tells us that $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ is only possible if $k = 0$, so let's handle that special case so we can use a more strict inequality to bound $x$.  So 
$$  (x)(y)(x+y)(2x+y) = 0  \text{,}  $$
is satisfied if $x = 0$, $y = 0$, $x = -y$, or $x = -y/2$.  So the solutions are $(0,0,y)$ for any integer $y$, $(0,x,0)$ for any integer $x$, $(0,-y,y)$ for any integer $y$, or $(0,x,-2x)$ for any integer $x$.  Now we may assume $x > 0$ in all further solutions and we need no particular sign choice for $y$.

So, if we have fixed a $k \neq 0$, we can let $x$ run through the positive divisors of $k$, and consider the reduced equation
$$  y(x+y)(2x+y) = k/x  \text{,}  $$
checking the divisors of $k/x$ for possible $y$s.

Example with $k = 210$: The divisors of $210$ are 
$$  1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 14, 15, 21, 30, 35, 42, 70, 105, \text{ and } 210  \text{.}  $$

- $x = 1$: $y(1+y)(2+y) = 210 / 1$, so $y$ must be the first of three consecutive factors of $210$.  That is $y = -7$, $y = -3$, $y = 1$ or $y = 5$.  $y = -7$ and $y = -3$ do not work because the product of three negative numbers is not positive.  $y = 1$ does not work because $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6 \neq 210$.  $y = 5$ does work.  So we have the solution $(210, 1,5)$.
- $x = 2$: $y(2+y)(4+y) = 210/2 = 105$, so we need three consecutive all-even or all-odd divisors of $105$.  The divisors of $105$ are $-105, -35, -21, -15, -7, -5, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 15, 21, 35, \text{ and } 105$, so $y = -7$, $y = -5$, $y = -3$, $y = -1$, $y =1$, and $y = 3$ are the only candidates.  $y = -7$, $y = -5$, and $y = -1$ give negative products.  $y = -3$ gives the product $-3 \cdot -1 \cdot 1 = 3 \neq 105$.  $y = 1$ gives $1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \neq 105$, but $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = 105$, so $(210, 2, 3)$ is a solution.
- $x = 3$: $y(3+y)(6+y) = 210/3 = 70$, so we need three divisors of $70$ in arithmetic progression with stride $3$.  The divisors of $70$ are $-70, -35, -14, -10, -7, -5, -2, -1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 10, 14, 35, \text{ and }70$, giving $y = -5$ and $y = -1$, but $-5 \cdot -2 \cdot 1 = 10 \neq 70$ and $-1 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 < 0$.
- $x = 5$: $y(5+y)(10+y) = 210/5 = 42$.  The divisors of $42$ are $-42, -21, -14,-7, -6,-3,-2, -1,1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 21, \text{ and }42$.  The candidate $y$s are $-7$ and $-3$.  The first gives $-7 \cdot -2 \cdot 3 = 42$ but the second gives a negative product, so we have the solution $(210, 5,-7)$.
- $x = 6$: $y(6+y)(12+y) = 210/6 = 35$.  The divisors of $35$ are $-35, -7, -5, -1, 1, 5, 7, 35$ and the candidates are $-7$, which works, and $-5$, which does not.  We have the solution $(210, 6, -7)$.
- $x = 7$: $y(7+y)(14+y) = 210/7 = 30$.  The smallest positive value this product takes is when $7+y = 1$, so $y = -6$, but then $-6 \cdot 1 \cdot 8 > 30$, so there are no solutions with $x \geq 7$.

Unrolling all of the above, we have eight solutions, $(210, 1, 5)$, $(210, 2, 3)$, $(210, 5, -7)$, $(210, 6, -7)$, and the four other members of their sign-swapped pairs ($(210, -1, -5)$, $(210, -2, -3)$, $(210, -5,7)$, and $(210, -6,7)$).

I make no claim to minimality of the above.  There should be shortcuts to detect impossible $x$s, by reducing $y(x+y)(2x+y) = k / x$ modulo $x$ and/or modulo a few well-chosen primes.  We could probably work out a bound on $x$, something in the neighbourhood of $x \leq \sqrt{k}$, although that's not quite right.

---

Things we can quickly see:

- $k = \pm 1$: no solutions.  We are forced to pick $x = 1$, and there are no three consecutive integers whose product is $1$ or is $-1$.
- $k = \pm 2$: no solutions.  Same problem: For $x = 1$, three consecutive integers either includes $0$ or an integer whose magnitude is bigger than $2$.  For $x = 2$, the minimal product magnitude is $-3 \cdot -1 \cdot 1 = 3 > 2/2 = 1$.  So neither choice of $x$ yields a viable $y$.
- $k$ an odd prime, positive or negative, $p$.  This requires $x \in \{1, p\}$, so unless $p = \pm 3$, there are not three divisors of $p$ in arithmetic progression.  If $p = \pm 3$ and $x = 1$, the product of three consecutive integers is not $3$.  Alternatively, $x = 3$ forces $y(3+y)(6+y) = 3/3 = 1$, an impossibility.
- And we could keep going, working through more and more complicated prime factorizations of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$2 x^3 y + 3 x^2 y^2 + x y^3 = w$  -------(1)

Solution given by "Eric Towers" is only for, $w=210$.

Since equation $(1)$ is a fourth degree equation in

three variables $(x,y,w)$ it would be difficult to

get an algebraic solution. However, since 'OP" need's

different value's of "$w$" there are more numerical

solutions for different "$w$" & are shown below.

$w=96$,  ($x_1$, $y_1$)= (-4, 6) &   ($x_2$, $y_2$)=(2, 2)

$w=240$, ($x_1$, $y_1$)= (-5, 9) &   ($x_2$, $y_2$)=(4, 1)

$w=480$, ($x_1$, $y_1$)= (-6, 10) &   ($x_2$, $y_2$)=(4, 2)

Comment: @Eric Towers: Thank you for the solution. My question was more regarding the fact whether there exists a recursive method to find all values of $k$ where multiple solutions exist, if all the variables are constrained to be positive. Like some Chinese remainder theorem or something?

Comment: @RTn : You seem to have commented on Sam's answer, not mine.  It also seems you had additional content for your Question that is not present in your Question (and should be).

Comment: @Sam : You might check your $w = 240$ solutions.  I get $(x,y) \in \{(3,2), (5,-8)\}$.

Comment: Oops Sorry.. And I added the additional content to my original question. Thanks a lot @EricTowers

Answer (score 0):

Get equation in positive integers $2 x^3 y + 3 x^2 y^2 + x y^3 = k$.

Let $Y=2x^2+y^2$ and $X=Y+6xy$,

then $X^2-Y^2=12k$.

Solving in gp-code:

```
blk()=
{
 for(k=1, 1000,
  v= [];
  T= thue('X^2-1, 12*k);
  for(i=1, #T,
   X= T[i][1]; Y= T[i][2];
   if(X>0&&Y>0, if(((X-Y)%6)==0,
    z= (X-Y)/6;
    D= divisors(z);
    for(j=1, #D,
     x= D[j]; y= z/x;
     if(Y==2*x^2+y^2,
      v= concat(v, [[x,y]]);
     )
    )
   ))
  );
  if(#v, print("k = ",k,"    Solutions = ",v,"\n"))
 )
};
```

Solutions for k=1..1000:

```
? \r blk.gp
? blk()
k = 6    Solutions = [[1, 1]]
k = 24    Solutions = [[1, 2]]
k = 30    Solutions = [[2, 1]]
k = 60    Solutions = [[1, 3]]
k = 84    Solutions = [[3, 1]]
k = 96    Solutions = [[2, 2]]
k = 120    Solutions = [[1, 4]]
k = 180    Solutions = [[4, 1]]
k = 210    Solutions = [[2, 3], [1, 5]]
k = 240    Solutions = [[3, 2]]
k = 330    Solutions = [[5, 1]]
k = 336    Solutions = [[1, 6]]
k = 384    Solutions = [[2, 4]]
k = 480    Solutions = [[4, 2]]
k = 486    Solutions = [[3, 3]]
k = 504    Solutions = [[1, 7]]
k = 546    Solutions = [[6, 1]]
k = 630    Solutions = [[2, 5]]
k = 720    Solutions = [[1, 8]]
k = 840    Solutions = [[3, 4], [5, 2], [7, 1]]
k = 924    Solutions = [[4, 3]]
k = 960    Solutions = [[2, 6]]
k = 990    Solutions = [[1, 9]]
```

Sequence of $k$ is https://oeis.org/A073120